# c# - Create HttpWebRequest without http or https

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I want X-Frame-Options using c#.
For this I am creating like the following.

```
  HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(System.Uri.UnescapeDataString(url));
            string frameSupport = string.Empty;
            using (WebResponse webResponse = request.GetResponse())
                frameSupport = webResponse.Headers["X-Frame-Options"];
```

But when I pass url without http or https, I am getting the following issue.

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Net.FileWebRequest' to type 'System.Net.HttpWebRequest'.
```

Comment: I think the solution is obvious. Pass the proper scheme.  How is `WebRequest` supposed whether it's a file, ftp, http or https request? Why are you using an invalid URL in the first place?

Comment: Furthermore, there is no `HttpWebRequest.Create` method. This is a factory method defined on [WebRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/LIbrary/bw00b1dc(v=vs.95).aspx). The compiler generates a warning and Visual Studio adds squigglies when you try to call a base static method like this

Comment: Sometime user may enter url like "//google.com" without http or https. So the url will be redirect to the appropriate http or https. So for this we allowed the user to give input like this. Can we get web request using "//google.com"

Comment: Probably, if you run on linux and have such a folder. Although I think a Linux machine would interpret this as an SMB server ?

Comment: Seriously - use a proper URL. Why do you expect such invalid URLs to work at all? They don't. Browsers attempt to guess and actually *try* to hit multiple ULRs with various prefixes when you type incomplete addresses.

Comment: `//` is a protocol relative URL; it has no meaning when used as a vanilla URL outside of a browser.  If your user enters it, reject it and require an http/https prefix.

Comment: Start with `http://`. Servers that require https will redirect you to https anyway

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos,  I hope the redirection works only if the website user done the https redirection for http. Right?

Comment: If the request doesn't work, you can try `https:`.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `HttpWebRequest.Create`, you are actually calling `WebRequest.Create` (since `HttpWebRequest` extends `WebRequest`).
Therefore, the method is not only for http requests, but it tries to get the actual type of the request based on the uri scheme.
If you omit http(s) scheme, it can't know what type of request you are performing, so, in this case, it assumes it is a `FileWebRequest`